# ldd different output. Same binary different distros

Tags: ubuntu, centos, shared-libraries, ldd

When running the `ldd` utility to find the shared libs for `httpd`, I found the following scenario that I just can't explain:

On my `Ubuntu` box:

```
leon@lwaldman-linux:~/Uol/Lxc/py_utils/Container_Builder/_builds/usr/sbin$ ldd  httpd 
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77b2000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7712000)
    libpcre.so.0 => not found
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0xf76f2000)
    libaprutil-1.so.0 => not found
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0xf76c1000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xf7697000)
    libdb-4.7.so => not found
    libapr-1.so.0 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf767b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf74d6000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77b3000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf74d1000)
```

And on a `CentOS` box:

```
[root@localhost sbin]# ldd httpd 
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x008b6000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x0036f000)
libpcre.so.0 => /lib/libpcre.so.0 (0x00835000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0x0021f000)
libaprutil-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0 (0x00dfa000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/libcrypt.so.1 (0x003de000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/libexpat.so.1 (0x00695000)
libdb-4.7.so => /lib/libdb-4.7.so (0x0040e000)
libapr-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00110000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00257000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00e37000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00aae000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x0096d000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/libuuid.so.1 (0x007c8000)
libfreebl3.so => /lib/libfreebl3.so (0x00d94000)
```

Why the **libuuid** and the **libfreebl3** are listed on the `CentOS` box but are not listed on the `Ubuntu` box?

I know that the `httpd ELF` doesn't list them as a dependency:

```
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so.6]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libpcre.so.0]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libselinux.so.1]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libaprutil-1.so.0]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libcrypt.so.1]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libexpat.so.1]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libdb-4.7.so]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libapr-1.so.0]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

Any insights?

EDIT: The httpd binary used on both tests was the same one (That I unpacked from the CentOS RPM).

Comment: Some libraries are not found on Ubuntu, but they are found on Centos and they might themselves pull other libraries.

Comment: For the libuuid it was indeed the case (needed by the libaprutil-1). But I couldn't find any thing on the libfreebl3.

Comment: Did you run 'ldd -v' to check who calls libfreebl?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! :)
The ldd -v showed that the libfreebl3 is indeed a dependency for the libcrypt, but only on the CentOS version of the libcrypt. On the Ubuntu version it's not listed).

Answer (score 3):

Propably Apache was built (compiled) with different options on Fedora and Ubuntu.

Maybe comparing the output of

```
httpd -V
```

will tell you more about that.

Comment: Actually on both tests I was using the CentOS Binary. Will edit the question.

Comment: Then the 'extra' libraries should be dependencies triggered by httpd direct dependencies, which change between Ubuntu and Fedora because these 'direct' dependencies have been compiled with different options on both distros.  EDIT: Basile Starynkevitch's comment seems to agree with me.

Answer (score 2):

`man ldd(1)` says that:

In  the usual case, ldd invokes the standard dynamic linker (see ld.so(8)) with the LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS environment variable set to
       1, which causes the linker to display the library dependencies.  Be aware, however, that in some circumstances, some  versions  of  ldd
       may  attempt to obtain the dependency information by directly executing the program.  Thus, you should never employ ldd on an untrusted
       executable, since this may result in the execution of arbitrary code.  A safer alternative when dealing with untrusted executables is:

`$ objdump -p /path/to/program | grep NEEDED`

According to my experience, this can produce a better result than `ldd`.

Answer (score 0):

libapr-1 is called libapr-1.0 in ubuntu.  At least, it is in 12.04 anyway.